# HtmlAgilityPack - Nothing displays in the textbox

Tags: c#, xpath, visual-studio-2017, richtextbox, html-agility-pack

I have a Windows Form with a text box, and the code is suppose to pull information from a website using the xpath I got via chromes developer tools and display it in said text box.

The problem is when I run the program nothing displays in the text box. I'm not sure if my code that is used to get the information is wrong or if my code to display said information is wrong. Please note this code utilizes HtmlAgilityPack.

Here is the code in question:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Url = "https://apps.ko.com/aami/iguest/default.asp";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

        string username = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/center/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/strong")[0].InnerText;
        string password = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/center/div/table/tr[2]/td[2]/strong")[0].InnerText;
        string summary = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/center/div/table/tr[4]")[0].InnerText;


        richTextBox1.Text = "User Name: " + username + " | Password: " + password + " | Summary: " + summary;

    }
```

There is a username and password listed on the intranet page and I'm trying to pull it from the webpage and display it in the text box, and so long as this app is being run on a domain machine it should be able to access the page and show the required information. I'm not trying to login to anything, just pull some text from a webpage.

None of you can see the page because your not on the domain where its only accessible from.

Here is the pages HTML with the web addresses in the code changed for security reasons.

```html
<body>
<div style="background-image:url(intranet.com/images/headergraphic_repeat_tile.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; width:100%; height:118px; padding:0px;">
<img src="https://intranet.com/iguest/images/headergraphic_extended.jpg" align="right">
</div>
<center>
<div style="width:390px; padding:20px; ">
    <h2 align="center">Guest Wireless Access</h2>
    <p align="left">Guests may access the wireless service by using the log-in <br>credentials below. <br>
      <br>
    </p>
  <table width="360" align="left" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td width="63">User ID:</td>
      <td><strong>KOGUEST</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><strong><span id="iguestpw">P@ssword</span></strong> <font size="-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;(Password is case-sensitive.)</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="-2">  The password is updated once a week on<br> Saturday at midnight EST.<br></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><br><br><p align="left"><a href="https://partner.intranet.com/sites/kooffice/training/documentation/guest wireless access_instructions for connecting.doc" target="_blank">Print  instructions</a> for your guest.<!--  or <a href="https://partner.intranet.com/sites/kooffice/training/i want to/courtesy wireless access.aspx" target="_blank">visit DWP</a> to learn more.--></p></td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody></table>
  </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: With that Html, your xpath are missing `tbody`. Inside `table` tag, there's a `tbody` tag, and the rows of the table are inside that `tbody`. For example the first xpath should be `/html/body/center/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong`

Comment: I read some where the come adds the tbody by mistake, but i got that xpath using chrome so its probably wrong and i have no clue how to write the xpath my self

Comment: In Firefox, you right click an element, press "inspect". Then right click on the Html tag and copy xpath. Also you can shorten and test xpaths in Console using this $x("my xpath here"). The idea is to write something like `//td[text()='User ID:']/following-sibling::td/strong` instead of full path. Note double slash `//` in the beginning. With this it will find it anywhere it is. Chrome inspection tools also are good.

Answer (score 1):

You're copying an xpath from you got from a browser - which is highly unreliable. And I don't know whether the website has a different HTML depending on region. But I do not have 'strong' tag or a 'center' tag in mine.

Do a proper xpath that doesn't rely on an xpath you got from a browser - they are prone to changes and will break your program if small changes occur (already proven by the fact that the xpath does not work on my end). It is very easy to just do a simple one. Because what you have now does not give a clear indication of what you want while an xpath that relied on the attributes and content of the tags would.

Also to expand on your followup question(s) since I can already tell what you're trying to do... You cannot just put in your username and password by using HtmlAgilityPack and then log in. You can either analyze the webpackets with Fiddler and replicate how you login. Or you can go the easier route and use Selenium with a headless browser such as Phantomjs.

Finally. When you do make your xpaths look at the PAGE SOURCE. Do NOT inspect the elements. The page source represents the HTML that gets loaded into your HtmlDocument. IF you inspect elements you get the source code after some steps on site has happened(for instance if the site is depended on JS og ajax to update the content).